# ¿Cómo puedo contar el total de una columna por mes?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo este script en donde estoy realizando la suma de todos los registros, la columna servicio_No es AUTO_INCREMENT necesito contar la cantidad de registros por mes para presentar estadisticas de cantidad.

```
<?php
    $conexion =  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root","admin123","database");
    $consulta="SELECT SUM(servicio_No) as totalServicios FROM servicio";
    $resultado=$conexion -> query($consulta);
    $fila=$resultado->fetch_assoc(); //que te devuelve un array asociativo con el nombre del campo

    $totalServicios = $fila['totalServicios']; //Este es el valor que acabas de calcular en la consulta

    echo $totalServicios;
?>
```

Comment: Deberias de incluir la estructura de la tabla `servicio`

Comment: @alanfcm ya mostre la estructura

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás sumando los valores de ese campo, no debes sumarlos, sino contarlos, el sql debería ser:

```
SELECT COUNT(servicio_No) as totalServicios FROM servicio
```

Si quieres agrupar esas respuestas por mes:

```
SELECT COUNT(servicio_No) as totalServicios FROM servicio GROUP BY mes //aquí el nombre del campo que corresponda a los meses
```

PD: Necesitas tener una columna en esa tabla que se dedique a recoger el mes en la que se realiza el servicio

Comment: pero como lo hago por mes

Comment: Edito la respuesta

Comment: si quieres lo puedes hacer

Comment: xD no era una pregunta, iba a hacerlo xD

Comment: dentro mi estructura de base de datos no tengo una columna por fecha de solicitud y al contar no es el resultado correcto me cuenta los registro de la fecha actual mas no todos los del mes

Comment: @CristianAntonioTrujilloGris por eso hay que mostrar la estructura COMPLETA de la tabla. Para no dar respuestas con suposiciones. De paso, es recomendable poner la sentencia DDL con la que se creat la tabla, como texto, en vez de imágenes. :)

Comment: como se hace eso

Comment: @ Alfabravo me puedes ayudar?